# how to update 2nd schema using node js (mongdb)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to update my 2nd schema which having reference in first schema

ownerSchema.js

```
var ownerSchema = Schema({
    fname     : String,
    lname     : String,
    shopPlace : { 
                  type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                  ref: 'Shop'
                }
});
var Owner = mongoose.model('Owner', ownerSchema);
```

shopSchema.js

```
var shopSchema = Schema({
    shopName  : String,
    location  : String,
    startDate : Date,
    endDate   : Date
});
var Shop  = mongoose.model('Shop', shopSchema);
```

so I am trying to update my schema like this

```
const update = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  let update = {};
  if (req.body.fname) update.fname = req.body.fname;
  if (req.body.lname) update.lname = req.body.lname;
  if (req.body.shopPlace.shopName) update.shopPlace.shopName = req.body.shopPlace.shopName;
  if (req.body.shopPlace.location) update.shopPlace.location = req.body.shopPlace.location;

   let newOwmer = new Owner.updateOne(
     { ownerId: id },
      {
        $set: update,
      },
      { runValidators: true }
     );
};
```

I am trying to update shop but its not working and where am i wrong i dont know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  const update = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  let update = {};
  let updateShop = {}
  if (req.body.fname) update.fname = req.body.fname;
  if (req.body.lname) update.lname = req.body.lname;
  if (req.body.shopPlace.shopName) updateShop.shopPlace.shopName = req.body.shopPlace.shopName;
  if (req.body.shopPlace.location) updateShop.shopPlace.location = req.body.shopPlace.location;

   // get shopPlace _id from Owner
   const { shopPlace } = await Owner.findOneAndUpdate(
     { _id: id },
      {
        $set: update,
      },
      { new:true}
     );
     // here you must have the document you just updated. Just recover the id of the shop to modify it in turn

    // update shop
    let newShop = await Shop.findOneAndUpdate(
     { _id: shopPlace },
      {
        $set: updateShop,
      },
      {new:true}
     );

};
```

Comment: no its not working :(

Comment: still i can't update my shopDetails

Comment: It's possible that you made a copy/paste of the code. Try to adapt it to your problem. Already to start change { ownerId: id } by {_id: id}.  I put the answer according to what you posted hoping that you adapt it. Normally it should work. Otherwise I make a small modification